# How to access to a Docker container in a Bitbucket pipeline

Tags: docker, maven, bitbucket-pipelines

My Maven Java project needs to execute integration test in the following Bitbucket pipeline:

```
learn-pipeline:
  - step:
      name: purpose merely learning about how pipeline is working
      services:
        - docker
      script:
        - docker run --detach --name some-mariadb --env MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD=1 --env MARIADB_DATABASE=test mariadb:latest
        - docker ps
        - mvn clean verify
```

The first script is `docker run` to start a MariaDB container for the *integration test* to use. The last script `mvn clean verify` is to run the integration test, which is accessing to the MariaDB *docker container*

This Bitbucket pipeline is able to start the *MariaDB* Docker container, but **problem** is that **the integration test is not able to access to the MariaDB database though `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test` with error `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`**

**Question**: How to successfully access to the MariaDB Docker Container? is the jdbc address I defined wrong?

Comment: Localhost is very rarely what you think when working with docker!

Comment: Why are you booting up a docker image yourself and not run it as a service? https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/databases-and-service-containers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use regular [pipeline services](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/databases-and-service-containers/) instead.

```yaml
definitions:
  services:
    mariadb:
      image: mariadb:latest
      variables:
        MARIADB_DATABASE: test
        MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Test
        services:
          - mariadb
        script:
          - mvn clean verify
```

Accessing a detached docker process should also work, but most probably you simply forgot to expose the database port in the `docker run --publish=3306:3306 whatnot` instruction. Using `localhost` in the URI should be fine. But pipeline services would take care about that for you.

Answer (score 0):

> How to successfully access to the MariaDB Docker Container?

Do not use the socket to connect to the MariaDB server but the IPv4 or IPv6 address (`localhost` is socket on Linux), Network is (was?) host network, use `127.0.0.1` instead in Bitbucket Pipelines.

> [... I]s the jdbc address I defined wrong?

Yes, the address is wrong, that's the essence of the error message:

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused